# How to use generic function interface method type parameters in a lambda

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8

Im trying to create a generic lambda so I dont need to redefine it for individual types. To do that I need to access the type parameters that were passed to the function. Unfortunately I didnt find any documentation on how to do that.

This is an example of what I want to do but the  in front of the lambda wont compile:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {

    interface SolveFunction {
        <In, Out> Out apply(In in);
    }

    public static void main(String...args) {
        SolveFunction f = <In, Out> (In a)  -> {
            ArrayList<Out> list = new ArrayList<>();
            return list;
        };
        System.out.println(f.<String, Integer>apply("Hi").size());
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? There are many things in this code that won't compile...

Comment: Im trying to implement the Divide and Conquer Pattern which accepts 4 functions: Divide, Solve, Trivial and Combine, heres the larger piece of code why I want generics inside the lambda https://dpaste.de/R6ew#L76 (code not tested yet since it breaks when at the generics when i try to compile it)

Comment: FYI this is not production code and I know that Java is not inteded to be used as a functional language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, add the type arguments to the interface itself:

```
interface SolveFunction<In, Out> {
    Out apply(In in);
}
```

You could implement a method:

```
public static <In, Out> List<Out> makeList(In in) {
    return new ArrayList<Out>();
}
```

Which you can then use as the implementation of the lambda:

```
SolveFunction<String, Integer> f = Test::makeList;

System.out.println(f.apply("Hi").size());
```

Comment: Note also that you wouldn't even need your `SolveFunction` interface, there's already an interface in the standard library that looks the same: `java.util.function.Function<T, R>`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure about what you're trying to use your ArrayList for but you need to add the type declaration to the interface as well. The following example will compile:

```
public class Test {

    interface SolveFunction<In, Out> {
        Out apply(In in);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SolveFunction<String, Integer> f = new SolveFunction<String, Integer>() {

            @Override
            public Integer apply(String in) {
                return in.length();
            }
        };

        System.out.println(f.apply("Hi")); // Prints 2
        System.out.println(f.apply("HELLO")); // Prints 5
    }
}
```

Comment: But it doesn't use Java 8 lambda syntax and the method uses concrete types (`String` and `Integer`) and not type parameters.